# chromium-browser is stuck at version 37.0.2062.120 on Ubuntu 12.04 (using precise-updates)

Tags: 12.04, chromium

Why is it stuck at v37 when Chromium v39 is already in trusty-updates, for example? Precise is still supported, right? The maintainers are also the same…

Comment: or you could download the deb package manually and install. updates are not very frequent

Comment: edward: Which deb? chromium v39 from trusty?

Comment: edward: Oh, I didn’t realise you were talking about Google Chrome. I do not want to use that (Google spyware). Open-source Chromium (minus Google stuff) is the way to go for me, at least! Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I have answered below

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Only security patches for major security holes and apocalyptic-level bugs are issued in "maintenance support" period. If you don't want to upgrade release, you can either use backports or add chromium PPA or switch to Google Chrom.

Comment: I have precise-backports already enabled in my Software Sources. Latest chromium is not there either. What ppa can I use? The chromium-stable ppa is outdated. I don’t want to use Google Chrome spyware. As Firefox is still up-to-date, I thought chromium would be too. Thanks!

Comment: @Barafu-Albino So, in regards to security, there isn't any issue using the default chromium, version 37, from the software repository?

Comment: Yes, of cause. The browser needs to be update regulary, unless you switch Javascript, Flash and all extensions off.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this picture, it says that: Canonical does not provide updates for Chromium:

[image: Screenshot of Chromium from Ubuntu Software Center]

If you want to get updates for Chromium take this PPA (on Ubuntu 12.04; for other versions go to this [page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/chromium_stable_channel)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now you should get a prompt to update Chromium, if it is already installed. if not run this:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: But that ppa only has chromium 30! The standard repos are less outdated than that! Also, I know that Canonical doesn’t support chromium directly, but the volunteer team responsible for it had already pushed out 39 for Trusty, so I though it would be the same for Precise, it being still supported and all. Kinda weird.

Comment: @omnomnom I will be better if you upgrade your ubuntu to 14.04 which is much stable.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Is there any security issues in using the default chromium, version 37, from the software repository?

Comment: @Abdul of course, using older version browser is security issue. newer browsers have bugs fixed

Answer (score 1):

The OP is correct, there is no Chromium update to 37 for Precise. This is a known bug and has been reported to launchpad bugs. The stable repository has not been maintained for a few years and adding the "stage" repository will result in upgrading to 48 which won't work on 12.04. As of now this is a problem as 37 is not compatible with the latest libnss3 update and any machine with chromium 37 & libnss3 update can't access google sites or content.